# C# OleDB Excel get rows/columns with text with formatting

Tags: c#, .net, excel, formatting, oledb

I have an excel file in which information was dumped, one name per line. The formatting of each line indicates the type of name it is, e.g a header/parent, or a child. 
When I use OleDB to fetch each row with appropriate column and get the text, I find all formatting has been removed. This means I cannot figure out whether it's supposed to be a parent or a child.

In short: How do I use OleDB with Excel files to get not only the TEXT but also the FORMATTING of the text? Thanks!

Comment: Is using interop out of the question?  It seems this task should be [relatively] easy if you used interop.

Comment: I'm using OleDB with the MS Access database engine, because I don't have MS Office installed, only LibreOffice. I could get MS Office but it would seem like a trival thing to get the formatting since I already have access to the text.. Crossed my mind though!

Comment: I see... that's a good answer.  I don't think OleDB can detect formatting.  It's core function is to read stuff like a database would.  There are alternatives, however, even if you don't have MS Office installed.  If you're open to those, let me know and I can try show an example of how you could do this.

Comment: @Hambone Well someone did it with a macro instead (they had MS Office installed) and that worked, but I'm actually curious as to what alternatives there are available for these cases. Would you care to share?

Comment: There are a handful of third party DLLs that will let you read and/or write spreadsheets without Excel.  I haven't played with all of them -- I think they have their pros and cons.  "SpreadsheetLight" looks promising for what you want.  See this example:  http://spreadsheetlight.com/downloads/samplecode/ModifyExistingSpreadsheet.cs .  `wb.GetCellStyle("A5").Font.FontColor` is an example of how to get the text color for cell A5.